# calculate modularity for each community not communities or whole partitioning?

Tags: graph, networkx, modularity, complex-networks

I'm currently working on a project where I need to calculate the modularity for each community as a quality metric in Python or using NetworkX. I know that NetworkX can calculate modularity for the entire partitioning, but I'm interested in calculating it for each individual community.

I've considered using metrics like density, but I'm unsure about how to proceed. Does anyone have any advice or suggestions on how I can calculate the modularity for each community using Python or NetworkX?

Thank you in advance!